# large image not showing in Angular 5

Tags: angular, image, angular5

I am still learning angular 5 and looks not complicated but some stuffs are strange... I have some image in my assets folder... When I refer any image smaller than 1MB, it get show no problem but when the image is like 1500Mb, for some reason, I get this error : "http://localhost:4200/assets/img/d4.jpg 404 (Not Found)"... But the image is there... What stranger is that if I select a smaller image, it is shown...
How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the issue, but... 1500MB (or even 1500Mb) for an image?!

Comment: 1500mb image will for certain timeout yr html page.. Are you sure of the size?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out nothing was wrong... Just that the image extension was JPG and I was referring it as jpg... Now it is working.